# Scaling Bezier Curves in Edit Mode vs Object Mode

Tags: edit-mode, scale, object-mode

If we create a bezier cruve (`[shift]+[a]`, "Curve", "Bezier") we get a slightly curved curve with two nodes along the x-axis.

If we enter edit mode, select everything and scale it with respect to the y-axis (`[s],[y],[0],[enter]`) to zero, everything behaves as we'd expect it.

However if we say in object mode and scale the curve to zero with respect to the y-axis (same commands as above) and *then* switch to the edit mode, I noticed that the "handles" of the nodes can only be rotated within the x-z-plane, but not into y-direction anymore.

So far I had the impression that this scaling does the same thing no matter whether we are in edit mode or object mode, but this is apparently not the case. So my question is:

> When are these two scaling methods *not* equivalent?

Comment: Applying scale solves that which is applying changes to the curve data and resetting object scale to 1. However I wouldn't say this is expected behaviour, maybe limitation or bug. The only guess I have is that curve normals after scaling in Object mode to 0 by Y axis become 0-size and inaccessible